# Convert time to duration

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, intervals, date-arithmetic

I have raw data in a table where I get a duration in the form of text string "4:30 hrs." What's a good way to parse that and convert into minutes? For example, "4:30 hrs." would parse into the integer 270.

Comment: can you post an example of the list? What if there are no hours? Is it like `0:40 hrs`?

Comment: Right, it'd be `0:40 hrs.` if it's less than an hour. Or `29:40 hrs.` if it's more than a day. There are guarantees on the max/min times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres is flexible enough to turn string `'4:30 hrs'` to an `interval` by just casting it.

Then all that is left to do is turn the interval to minutes, which you can do by extracting `epoch` from it, and dividing the result by `60`.

So I would just go:

```
extract(epoch from '4:30 hrs'::interval) / 60
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=89c02775d49c177fdf11487bc0a5f812)**:

```
select mycol, extract(epoch from mycol::interval) / 60 res
from (values ('04:30 hrs'::text), ('29:40 hrs'::text)) as t(mycol)
```

```
mycol     | res 
:-------- | :---
04:30 hrs | 270 
29:40 hrs | 1780
```

Comment: I'll have to strip the trailing `.`, but otherwise this works!